# How to order by a datetime column and show the unique date part values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a datetime type column in SQL Server 2012. I want to display the unique date part of the column sorted by that column ascending.

I tried this query but it orders by string type. There must be a simple query but I am missing it.

```
select distinct(convert(varchar, CreatedDate, 101)) from sometable order by 1
```

**Update:**
I am adding the DDL statements. I thought this is a straightforward query with a quick easy answer.

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [Test]([CreatedDate])  
VALUES(CAST('20161231 14:00:00.000' as DATETIME))
INSERT INTO [Test]([CreatedDate])  
VALUES(CAST('20170101 12:00:00.000' as DATETIME))
INSERT INTO [Test]([CreatedDate])
VALUES(CAST('20170101 11:00:00.000' as DATETIME))
INSERT INTO [Test]([CreatedDate])
VALUES(CAST('20170101 10:00:00.000' as DATETIME))
INSERT INTO [Test]([CreatedDate])
VALUES(CAST('20170201 03:00:00.000' as DATETIME))
INSERT INTO [Test]([CreatedDate])
VALUES(CAST('20160403 02:00:00.000' as DATETIME))
```

**Expected Results:**

```
04/03/2016  
12/31/2016  
01/01/2017  
02/01/2017
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: And what is wrong with that query?
    Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Distinct is not a function with paramaters... it is a statement or tag. `select distinct convert(varchar, CreatedDate, 101) from sometable order by 1` get rid of the ()'s  DISTINCT always operates on all columns in the final result
DISTINCT is not a function that accepts a column as an argument

Comment: @Tim: just different dates with times. Not sure why actual values matter here

Comment: @Juan I told you what's wrong. It sorts by strings.I assumed you know what that meant. It shows '12/20/2016' before '08/26/2016' when sorted ascending.  Also did you actually try your answer you posted? I hope that page also tells you to test your answers before you post them.  It gives an erro

Comment: Yes I know what that mean, so please drop the actitude. One will expect a better formulated question for someone with 12k rep. And I would test my answer if you provide some sample data but looks like you didnt have time for that. I may have make a mistake but that should guide you on the right direction.

Comment: Your expected result doesnt match the `101` format. Also your sample doesnt include any duplicated data so doesnt show the need from `DISTINCT`

Comment: 101 is mm/dd/yyyy  and you have no duplicates

Comment: I edited the ddl. I should have tested everything

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you need to do something like this:

```
select convert(varchar, CreatedDate, 101)
from (
    select distinct convert(date, CreatedDate) as CreatedDate 
    from sometable
) X
order by CreatedDate
```

Because you can't order by a different field that you have used for distinct.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer with the current sample data [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/YPE22846)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `distinct` to `group by`. This will allow you to use the original column for sort:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), CreateDate, 101)
FROM someTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(char(10), CreateDate, 101)
ORDER BY AVG(CreateDate)
```

Thanks to Juan Carlose Oropeza for creating a demo in rextester - I came up with this solution that [seems to be working fine](http://rextester.com/MZS62186):

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), CAST(CreatedDate as Date), 101)
FROM Test
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedDate as Date)
ORDER BY CAST(CreatedDate as Date)
```

Comment: Error: Column "CreateDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Operand data type datetime is invalid for avg operator.  [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/TQYWD28068)

Comment: Edited once again... Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: This also looks correct, OP should test to see what is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the problem is you are getting order by the string sort by the date.

```
select distinct convert(varchar, CreatedDate, 101)
from sometable 
order by CreatedDate
```

Comment: Error message: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias for the column, use the alias to order by.

<strike>select 
        distinct(convert(varchar,CreatedDate,101)) as OrderedDate 
    from sometable
    order by OrderedDate</strike>

instead of distinct you can use group by to achieve what you want.

<strike>select 
          convert(varchar,CreatedDate,101) as OrderedDate 
   from sometable
     Group By CreatedDate
     order by CreatedDate</strike>

The below Code works as expected. tested too.

```
select 
    convert(varchar,x.OrderedDate,101) 
from
(
 select 
    distinct cast(CreatedDate as date)  OrderedDate
 from 
 Test 
    ) x
 order by x.OrderedDate
```

Comment: Nope. You're aliasing the result which is a string. 1 in my example does the same thing

Comment: maybe you should `GROUP BY convert(varchar,CreatedDate,101)`

Comment: GROUP BY convert(varchar,CreatedDate,101) will kill the order by clause.